# Python / Django: sending emails resulting in 535 (for gmail email works)

Tags: python, django, email, sendmail

For sending the form I have a script in AJAX, which runs the e-mail trigger function. The following error is returned:

```
EMAIL_HOST='mail.example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER='no-reply@example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='xxx'
EMAIL_PORT='25'
```

For sending the form I have a script in AJAX, which runs the e-mail trigger function. The following error is returned:

```
SMTPAuthenticationError at /vendas/contato/
(535, 'Incorrect authentication data')
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://example.com/vendas/contato/
Django Version: 1.3
Exception Type: SMTPAuthenticationError
Exception Value:    
(535, 'Incorrect authentication data')
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py in login, line 622
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['/home/example/pythonenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-12.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/example/pythonenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/example/src/myproject']
Server time:    Seg, 26 Set 2016 17:08:45 -0300
```

After some testing, I found that when sending a message to a gmail email for example, it is sent normally, other areas such as `example.com` or `example.net` result in `error 535`.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: I thought the fact that I report the error and the status of the shipment to be working for gmail addresses to help identify a possible common mistake.

Comment: Can you show the python code that sends an actual email?